# TL431 LDO series pass transister heating up

Tags: voltage-regulator, 5v, ldo, tl431

I designed a low drop out 5v voltage regulator from 24v input. Works fine. But the series pass transistor heating up more than 100 degree Celsius (with heat sink). Is it normal? Or how to reduce heat? Consumption is 150 mA, running a dsPIC30F2010. Explanation or correction or suggestion most appreciated. Resources I am stuck with TL431/MJE13003, cuz other ready made LDO products not available in the local market. Circuit included.[image]

Comment: 19 V x 0.15 A = 2.85 W. What is the \$\theta\$ of your heatsink?

Comment: Kindly ignore the symbol for TL431, its connected correctly. just that could not find a better symbol in "fritzing" for TL431.

Comment: No idea,@The Photon, just took from a mosfet.

Comment: Then the answer is get a heatsink with a known thermal resistance that meets your need for limiting the device temperature with ~3 W consumed.

Comment: Or change to a switching regulator so you can get better than 20% efficiency.

Comment: @The Photon, Kindly suggest some switching regulator.

Comment: There are thousands available, but you made a point that some parts are not available in your market. I have no idea what is available in your market, so I can't help with that.

Comment: All I can tell you is you're looking for a *buck regulator*.

Answer (score 2):

Dropping 24 v down to 5v is very inefficient, most of the input power will end up as heat in your series pass element, regardless of its part number.

150mA at nearly 20v drop is nearly 3 watts. If the transistor is getting too hot, use a larger heatsink, or a lower input voltage.

If you are stuck with using an input voltage at the top end of your range, then putting a series resistor before the transistor would shift some of the dissipation away from it, to allow you to use the existing heatsink. This does not affect the output regulation, that's still controlled by the transistor/431. You could halve the dissipation by dropping 9v in this way, which would need a series resistor of 9v/150mA = 60ohms. Of course, you'd need to use a resistor that could dissipate at least 1.5watts.

A better way that does not sacrifice the ability to work from lower input voltages would be to use a dropper transistor on a different heatsink, biassed from a resistive divider such that it splits the voltage drop across both transistors, to equalise their heat generation.

What we tend to do these days is to use a buck switching regulator, which loses far less heat, by drawing only the power needed from the power supply, not the full current.

Comment: Thank you @Neil_UK, VCC is 24v, have to drive the mosfet drivers using a dsPIC30F2010 VDD is 5v. Using a series resister and bulky heat sink is the solution. Otherwise got to design a buck converter or use a buck converter chip.

Comment: *Otherwise got to design a buck converter or use a buck converter chip* I would suggest a **much easier** solution: use a ready made module. Here's an example: https://www.ebay.com/itm/LM2596-DC-DC-4V-35V-to-1-23V-30V-Step-Down-Power-Module-Voltage-Regulator-3A-/251066005460  That will save you a lot of trouble as it will just **work**. You could/make/design your own but you are very likely to run into all kinds of issues.

Comment: Good news. Found LM2576-12/LM2576-5/LM2576-Adj, thanks to @Neil_UK @ Bimpelrekkie. Looked for buck converter IC from net and ran to the market and searched for it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use BD1xx series transistor, precisely BD139. MJE13003 is used in mains switching transformer, not in low voltage application.

Comment: How will that help the OP? Using a different transistor doesn't change the amount of heat that needs to be dissipated.